# C# How to get the start date of the current 12 month cycle given a start date and an end date for a period

Tags: c#

How to get the start date of the current 12-month cycle given a start date and an end date for a period.

for example, the start date is 02/02/2016  and the end date is 18/04/2018.
current start date of the 12-month cycle would be 02/02/2018.

l have something calculating the period from the start date to the end date so it takes care of the cases where start date is after the end date. If the start date is the 29th of February when it's not a leap year it uses the next day (1 march) for that cycle only

Comment: What would you want to happen if the start date is February 29th? and the end date is in a non-leap-year? What would you want to happen if the start date is after the end date? (Is that an error?) Have you done anything to try to implement this yet?

Comment: As it stands, this doesn't look much like a programming question

Comment: So the `current start date of the 12-month cycle` is the start date in the year of the end date. Its not entirely clear what the requirement is.

Comment: l have something calculation the period from the start date to the end date so it takes care of the cases where start date is after the end date. If the start date is the 29th of February when it's not a leap year it uses the next day (1 march) for that cycle only.

Comment: Okay, so please include all of this information in the question, including how far you've got already. (I'd expect a method with a signature of `DateTime GetCurrentStartDate(DateTime originalStartDate, DateTime endDate)` or similar.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the date and month values for start date and the year value for end date and use it to set current start date:

```
DateTime startDate = (Convert.ToDateTime("02/02/2016"));
var dy = startDate.Day;
var mn = startDate.Month;

DateTime endDate = (Convert.ToDateTime("18/04/2018"));
var yy = endDate.Year;

var currentStartDate = new DateTime(yy, mn, dy);
```

Comment: This won't currently compile for various reasons - and I'd strongly recommend using `DateTime.ParseExact` or `DateTime.TryParseExact` if the format is known. (I'd actually separate any string handling out from the rest of this question anyway.) Also, it's not clear what you expect this to do if `startDate` is February 29th and `endDate` isn't a leap year.

Comment: Thank you this is working, and giving the correct date am looking for. but the question of a leap year, any ideas l can handle that.

Comment: @Prince: you need add the extra check for that